# dabei, wobei Pronominal adverb

Tags: grammar-identification

> Er ging weg, wobei er hämisch grinste.
>
> Er ging weg und lachte dabei.

Are both pronominal adverb wobei  and dabei interchangeable in the above sentences?

Comment: "Hämisch grinsen" (to grin maliciously) is something different from "lachen" (to laugh)

Answer (score 5):

`wobei` and `dabei` are interchangable indeed, but they require a different sentence structure. They both refer to an action mentioned in the `Hauptsatz` (in the case of `dabei`, it can also be used in the Hauptsatz, then it refers to an action of the previous sentence)

`Wobei` is always at the beginning of the `Nebensatz` and it makes it a `Relativsatz`. `Dabei` does not need to stand at the beginning and it does not initiate a `Relativsatz`.

You can say these:

> Er ging weg und grinste dabei hämisch.
>   Er ging weg, wobei er lachte.
>   Er ging weg. Dabei grinste er hämisch.

But you cannot simply replace the words like this:

> Er ging weg, dabei er hämisch grinste.
>   Er ging weg und lachte wobei

Please note that the two used sentences don't really describe the same thing, as `lachen` and `hämisch grinsen` are quite different. My answer focuses on the difference of wobei and dabei.